# Error : " dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required " in Unit test

Tags: python, python-unittest, pyyaml

I have two files : database_config.py used to  to check connection to database via DatabaseConfig.yml configuration file. I need to write some test cases for my config file includes several scenarios :

1. If the database is empty then the test case fails.
2. If the database is not Sqlite or Postgre, test case fails.

I have created a test file but while I try to implement it  I am getting error

`ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`.

Could anyone please help me on this?

My DatabaseConfig.yml :

```
database: 

dbopt:
   host: None
   port: 6313
   dbname: spam_eggs2

query:
   select * from manufacturing_product
```

My database_config.py:

```
import yaml

class InvalidConfigError(Exception):
    pass

class DB():
    def __init__(self, dbconf):
        self._dbconf = dict(dbconf)
        # checking for database type
        dbtype = self.get_db_type()
        if dbtype != 'sqlite' and dbtype != 'postgres':
            raise InvalidConfigError(
                'E01001', 'Invalid database type, should be sqlite or postgres.')
        else:
            self.dbtype = dbtype

    def get_db_type(self):
        return self._dbconf['database']

with open('DatabaseConfig.yml') as f:
    data = yaml.full_load(f)

    for item, doc in data.items():
        print(item, ":", doc)

    database = DB(data)
```

My test file test_db_type.py for database_config.py:

```
import yaml
import unittest
import database_config

class TestDBtype(unittest.TestCase):
    #setUpClass gets calls only once where as setUp gets called before every test
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.init_db()

    @classmethod
    def init_db(cls):
        self.db_instance = database_config.DB('DatabaseConfig.yml')

    def test_missing_db(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.db_instance, None, "Connection returned None.")

    def test_db_type(self):
        with self.subTest():
            self.assertEqual(self.db_instance, 'postgres')
        with self.subTest():
            self.assertEqual(self.db_instance, 'sqlite')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Error Traceback when I run test:

```
(base) D:\Python>python -u "d:\Python\TestDataSource\test_db_type.py"
database : postgres
dbopt : {'host': 'None', 'port': 6313, 'dbname': 'spam_eggs2'}
query : select * from manufacturing_product
E
======================================================================
ERROR: setUpClass (__main__.TestDBtype)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\TestDataSource\test_db_type.py", line 9, in setUpClass
    cls.init_db()
  File "d:\Python\TestDataSource\test_db_type.py", line 13, in init_db
    self.db_instance = database_config.DB('DatabaseConfig.yml')
  File "d:\Python\TestDataSource\database_config.py", line 8, in __init__
    self._dbconf = dict(dbconf)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)

(base) D:\Python>C:/Users/duongnb/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/Scripts/activate

(base) D:\Python>conda activate base

(base) D:\Python>^A
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
self.db_instance = database_config.DB('DatabaseConfig.yml')
```

you're passing a single string argument to `DB` constructor; this argument is passed here:

```
class DB():
    def __init__(self, dbconf):
        self._dbconf = dict(dbconf)
```

but you cannot create a dict from a single argument - `dict('DatabaseConfig.yml')` raises error.

Comment: Waht should I do? Is it due to the structure of the yaml file?

Comment: It happens before you even open your YAML file. You should probably rethink your `DB` class.